# realtime database cloud function for matching if a node cantains 2 child and wait if it has not

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want a cloud function on real time database node, lets call 'waitingroom'

1. When 1st child inserted,then it wait for next child for 30 second for pairing.
2. If more than 2 child inserted at same time on this node then pair(2-2) them with random position 
   child and leave rest child to wait for another child to be inserted to pair with.
3. remove child from the node('waitingroom') if not paired with in 30seconds.

Every child contains key and value.Every Value contains name_imagename format data.When node contains minimum 2 child for pair then interchange value of both child(only value should be changed).

then insert final data to another node called 'matchingdone' with key and interchangedvalue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fire base you can run a query and then in the callback you can get the reference to the inserted child and check if there already exists a child with similar value.

```
     let counter = 0
     waitingroom.on("value", snap() => {
        if ( counter == 2 ){       
        // compare the child added have value similar to existing one
           Object.keys(snap.val()).map( k=> {
              matchingdone.push(snap.val()[k])
           })
        }
        counter++
      })
```